# What's the protocol for packaging external software with InstallShield?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, installation, installshield

My WPF project requires Adobe Reader. Apparently when I try and run the installer, it says I need to have it installed before I run the installer for my project.

I was wondering how do I package it along with InstallShield so that the user can select the option to have Adobe Reader install before installing the main project instead of having to search for it online themselves to install it?

Is this even possible? I tried to search online but I'm having hard time finding results.

Right now I'm using InstallShield Limited Edition for Visual Studio 2012.

EDIT:

Here's one screenshot where I picked the settings:

[image]

EDIT #2: I found a redistributable .exe of Adobe Reader 9.1. Now, I am wondering how I can tie that into InstallShield?

Comment: Isn't there an option in InstallShield to require Reader as a prerequisite?

Comment: Yup, I checked off Adobe Reader 10 and 9 as a prerequisite. When I ran the installer, I thought it would package it with the installer but it said something like I needed to have it installed before I run the installer :( I'll grab a screenshot and post it up soon.

Comment: Yeah; those won't directly include the installer, but just require it. I should have read more closely! ;) That said; isn't there a way to include them... or was that something not available in LE?

Comment: Oh, and while we're at it; does Adobe even make a redistrubutable installer?

Comment: What's essentially what I'm asking, I'm not sure how to include an installer for Adobe Reader into my InstallShield. So far, I don't see an option to. However, I could be overlooking something.

Comment: Yeah. I haven't been very helpful! haha... I'm positive it *can* do it, but I've not used InstallShield in a while. Don't know if that feature is limited, or if Reader can be redistributed. Hopefully someone will know...

Comment: @AndrewBarber, I have one more question... For some question, when I run the installer, the size of the installer on my machine is really tiny/looks compressed. Why do you think that could be happening and how can I fix it/adjust the size of the window/compression level? Thanks!

Comment: Btw, I found a redistributable version of Adobe Reader 9.1! Just need to tie it into InstallShield LE.